# Html Change body background with color result from SQL

Tags: html, css, sql, vbscript, background

I have search high and low but cant find the answer I need.

Here is my page. You will see that I am returning results from my SQL server from the tblPackageType table. This table holds color codes example #7A2D2D.

What I need to do is change my page background color based on the value returned.

I'm well off under standing how to do this, but i'm sure its something like

```
IF <%=(PackageType.Fields.Item("intPackageID").Value)%> = "" Then 
background-color="White"

Else

<%=(PackageType.Fields.Item("intPackageID").Value)%> = "1" Then
background-color=<%=(PackageType.Fields.Item("strPackageColor").Value)%>

else AND SO ON.....
```

---

```
    <%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="1252"%>
<%

Session.TimeOut = 10

If Session("MM_Username") = "" Then
response.redirect "/Account/LoginDenied.asp"
Else
// main page
End If

%>
<!--#include virtual="/Connections/LiveDataBase.asp" -->
<%
' IIf implementation
Function MM_IIf(condition, ifTrue, ifFalse)
  If condition = "" Then
    MM_IIf = ifFalse
  Else
    MM_IIf = ifTrue
  End If
End Function
%>
<%
' *** Restrict Access To Page: Grant or deny access to this page
MM_authorizedUsers="1"
MM_authFailedURL="/Admin/main.asp"
MM_grantAccess=false
If Session("MM_Username") <> "" Then
  If (false Or CStr(Session("MM_UserAuthorization"))="") Or _
         (InStr(1,MM_authorizedUsers,Session("MM_UserAuthorization"))>=1) Then
    MM_grantAccess = true
  End If
End If
If Not MM_grantAccess Then
  MM_qsChar = "?"
  If (InStr(1,MM_authFailedURL,"?") >= 1) Then MM_qsChar = "&"
  MM_referrer = Request.ServerVariables("URL")
  if (Len(Request.QueryString()) > 0) Then MM_referrer = MM_referrer & "?" & Request.QueryString()
  MM_authFailedURL = MM_authFailedURL & MM_qsChar & "accessdenied=" & Server.URLEncode(MM_referrer)
  Response.Redirect(MM_authFailedURL)
End If
%>
<%
' *** Logout the current user.
MM_Logout = CStr(Request.ServerVariables("URL")) & "?MM_Logoutnow=1"
If (CStr(Request("MM_Logoutnow")) = "1") Then
  Session.Contents.Remove("MM_Username")
  Session.Contents.Remove("MM_UserAuthorization")
  MM_logoutRedirectPage = "/index.asp"
  ' redirect with URL parameters (remove the "MM_Logoutnow" query param).
  if (MM_logoutRedirectPage = "") Then MM_logoutRedirectPage = CStr(Request.ServerVariables("URL"))
  If (InStr(1, UC_redirectPage, "?", vbTextCompare) = 0 And Request.QueryString <> "") Then
    MM_newQS = "?"
    For Each Item In Request.QueryString
      If (Item <> "MM_Logoutnow") Then
        If (Len(MM_newQS) > 1) Then MM_newQS = MM_newQS & "&"
        MM_newQS = MM_newQS & Item & "=" & Server.URLencode(Request.QueryString(Item))
      End If
    Next
    if (Len(MM_newQS) > 1) Then MM_logoutRedirectPage = MM_logoutRedirectPage & MM_newQS
  End If
  Response.Redirect(MM_logoutRedirectPage)
End If
%>

<%
Dim PackageType__varintCustomerID
PackageType__varintCustomerID = "0"
If (Request.QueryString("varintCustomerID") <> "") Then 
  PackageType__varintCustomerID = Request.QueryString("varintCustomerID")
End If
%>
<%
Dim PackageType
Dim PackageType_cmd
Dim PackageType_numRows

Set PackageType_cmd = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Command")
PackageType_cmd.ActiveConnection = MM_LiveDataBase_STRING
PackageType_cmd.CommandText = "SELECT        tblPackageType.intPackageID, tblPackageType.strPackageColor, tblPackageType.strPackageName FROM            tblCustomer LEFT OUTER JOIN                          tblPackageType ON tblCustomer.intPackage = tblPackageType.intPackageID WHERE tblCustomer.intCustomerID = ?" 
PackageType_cmd.Prepared = true
PackageType_cmd.Parameters.Append PackageType_cmd.CreateParameter("param1", 200, 1, 255, PackageType__varintCustomerID) ' adVarChar

Set PackageType = PackageType_cmd.Execute
PackageType_numRows = 0
%>

<html lang="en"><head>
  <title>Me2You</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">  
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Content/simple-sidebar.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/bootstrap-3.3.2-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Scripts/jquery-ui.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Content/table.css">
  <script src="/Scripts/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="/bootstrap-3.3.2-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>




</head>

<body>
<header>

</header>
    <div id="wrapper">
     <!-- Sidebar -->
        <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
            <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                <li class="sidebar-brand">
                    <a href="/Main/main.asp">
                        Menu
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/Main/NewCustomers/newapps.asp">New Customer</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/Main/ManageCustomer/customerlookup.asp">Manage Customer</a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Open Applications <span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="/Main/ManageCustomer/customerlookuplist.asp?varstrMerchantID=NoMerchantNumber">No Merchant Number</a></li>
      <li><a href="/Main/ManageCustomer/customerlookuplist.asp?varstrTerminalID=TBC">Terminals with TBC</a></li>
      <li><a href="/Main/ManageCustomer/QuickUpdate/customerlookuplistnoemaemailed.asp?varintCoverSheetEmailed=0">EMA Not Emailed</a></li>
      <li><a href="/Main/ManageCustomer/QuickUpdate/customerlookuplistnoemaposted.asp?varintCoverSheetPosted=0">EMA Not Posted</a></li>
      <li><a href="/Main/ManageCustomer/QuickUpdate/customerlookuplistnoing.asp?varintINGLeasePosted=0">INGLease Not Posted</a></li>
      <li><a href="/Main/ManageCustomer/QuickUpdate/customerlookuplistnogems.asp?varintLogoReceived=0">Gems/SAP Order Not Completed </a></li>
      <li><a href="/Main/ManageCustomer/QuickUpdate/customerlookuplistnowelcomeletter.asp?varintWelcomeLetterSent=0">Welcome Letter Not Sent</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
               <li><a href="/Main/ManageCustomer/customerlookuplist.asp?varintActiveStatus=1">Active Customers</a>    </li>  
 <li class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Queries <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="/Main/Queries/newquery.asp">Create New Query</a></li>
      <li><a href="/Main/Queries/openqueries.asp">Open Queries</a></li>
      <li><a href="/Main/Queries/recentupdatedqueries.asp">Recently Updated Queries</a></li>
      <li><a href="/Main/Queries/closedqueries.asp">Closed Queries</a></li>
      <li><a href="/Main/Queries/allqueries.asp">All Queries</a></li>

      </ul>
      <% If Not ReportsView.EOF Or Not ReportsView.BOF Then %>
      <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Report's <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="/Main/Reports/repnotcompleteddays.asp">Orders Not Completed By Age</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Main/Reports/repavgdays.asp">Avg Days To Complete</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Main/Reports/testreport3">Test Report 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>  
<% End If ' end Not ReportsView.EOF Or NOT ReportsView.BOF %>
 <% If Not BillingControl.EOF Or Not BillingControl.BOF Then %>
  <li><a href="/Main/Queries/billing.asp">Billing Control</a></li>
  <% End If ' end Not BillingControl.EOF Or NOT BillingControl.BOF %>
</li>
    </li>



            </ul>
        </div>
<div class="row">
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar"> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button>
            <div class="navbar-brand" style="padding-left:40px">Me2You</div> </div>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-left navbar-form">
                              <form action="/Main/ManageCustomer/main.asp">
                                <span style="color: #FFFFFF">Quick Goto Customer ID</span>
                                <input name="varintcustomerid" type="text" id="varintcustomerid" autocomplete="off" size="6"></form>
          </ul>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="padding-right:15px">
            <a href="<%= MM_Logout %>" class="btn btn-info btn-lg"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Logout</a>


            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
  </nav>
     <div class="row" style="padding:15px">
  <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="col-md-12">

  <a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-default" id="menu-toggle">Toggle Menu</a>&nbsp; <a href="/Main/main.asp" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Back</a></div>

   </div>
   </div>

  <div class="row" style="padding:15px"></div>           


       <div>
</div>              

       <div class="row" style="padding:15px">
         <div class="container"></div>
         <div class="clearfix visible-lg"></div>


  </div>

<footer>

</footer>
</div>
    <script>
    $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
    });
    </script>

</body>
</html>

<%
PackageType.Close()
Set PackageType = Nothing
%>
```

Any help would be great thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest putting the background color into a variable, and then writing that variable into a `style` tag.

```vbs
...
<head>
<%
dim bg
'... database stuff goes here
If PackageType("intPackageID") = "" Then
    bg = "white"
Else
    bg = PackageType("strPackageColor")
End If
'...blah blah blah
%>
<style type="text/css">
body {background-color:<%=bg%>;}
</style>
</head>
...
```

Depending on how your page is laid out, you may actually want to put the background color on a different element -- e.g. a div with a specific ID -- but this should be enough to get you started.

Comment: Thanks @Martha This worked exactly as i wanted. Then was able to mod the style to change div!